# opennebula how to find out a snapshot size?

Tags: opennebula

All I can see with the `onvvm show $vmid` command is:

```
SNAPSHOTS
  ID         TIME NAME                                           HYPERVISOR_ID
   0  03/16 06:47 VBE1                                           XXXXXXXXXX
   1  05/06 12:06 snapshot-1                                     XXXXXXXXXY
```

but I don't see:

- Snapshot's path, where the snapshot is stored/located on disk
- Snapshot's size

Someone has any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searches, I found the answer in some PDF file
https://dsn.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/projekty/backup/data/report.pdf

```
# VM files stored in
oneadmin@1.1.1.1: ~/datastores/0/$VMID

# Snapshots sizes
> cd ~/datastores/0/$VMID/
> qemu-img snapshot -l disk.0

Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         1426488438             5.9G 2015-03-16 06:47:18 2070:25:44.994
2         1430914004              12G 2015-05-06 12:06:44 3299:38:54.085
3         1431597375             9.4G 2015-05-14 09:56:15 3488:38:13.221
```